# WebStorm 11 Live Edit not working when use external css with Chrome 47

Tags: google-chrome, webstorm, liveedit

Live Edit works well when there is only html file,but whenever I change a external css file, there is no active change in Chrome.

I have open the Auto Update in Live Edit... Can any body help me? Thanks!
[This is my Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxogO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WEB-18886](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18886) is fixed in WebStorm 11.0.3 that is coming soon

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much!